# How to validate in-line outputs in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to validate a pure object that is the output of a Terraform source (used by other modules).  Specifically I want to validate it in the output declaration, rather than the parent module.  My understanding is that `precondition` expressions are allowed in `output` blocks, but I can't find a way to actually reference the output variable in-line:

```
output "this" {
  value = {
    foo = {
      bar = true
    }
  }

  # Doesn't work
  precondition {
    condition     = self.foo.bar != false
    error_message = "bar is false."
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

`Error: Invalid "self" reference: The "self" object is not available in this context. This object can be used only in resource provisioner, connection, and postcondition blocks.`

I tried other methods for referencing the output's "self" but they incur similar error message.  Is there a syntax that can achieve this?

Comment: I believe https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions describes the allowed syntax for conditions, and none of them are within `output`. Also I believe `self` is only allowed within `provisioner` so there would be two syntax violations here.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [custom conditions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions#preconditions-and-postconditions) is clear:

> Each precondition and postcondition requires a condition argument. This is an expression that must return true if the conditition is fufilled or false if it is invalid. The expression can refer to **any other objects** in the same module, as long as the references do not create cyclic dependencies. **Resource postconditions** can also use the self object to refer to attributes of each instance of the resource where they are configured.

emphasis mine. An output must refer to another object (and thus cannot use `self`).

Answer (score 0):

The `self` behavior only applies to *postconditions*, because they get checked after the the evaluation of the object they are associated with. A precondition cannot refer to `self` because that value hasn't been evaluated yet; the purpose of a precondition is to prevent evaluating the object if some prerequisite isn't met, so that the returned error can be about whatever the precondition was checking instead of about the expression that failed as a result of it.

Output values don't have postconditions because they don't have any inherent side-effects to react to. Output values have preconditions primarily to prevent an incorrect value from being exported from a configuration that might then be consumed using `terraform_remote_state` or `tfe_outputs`, and might therefore break the consumer of that information.

---

The example you shared seems contrived because the hypothetical postcondition you wrote could never fail; the value it would be checking is hard-coded right above and is set to a value that passes the condition.

However, in a more realistic scenario where the output value is built from something else you can use a precondition to check whatever other objects the `value` expression refers to. For example:

```
output "public_ip" {
  value = aws_instance.example.public_ip

  precondition {
    condition     = aws_instance.example.public_ip != ""
    error_message = "EC2 instance does not have a public IP address."
  }
}
```

This will prevent the evaluation of the `value` expression, and therefore the exporting of the output value, if the value would end up being the empty string.